# Buying bunnies, eggs and elections with tax and a discount

Tags: python, beginner

I have a small problem with the code below. Although it executes the task perfectly, It's supposed to be more "short" and compact according to the assignment feedback. I was wondering if someone can please help me change my code from its longer version to a more short version that completes the same task...

```
from math import *

ask = input("Would you like to buy bunnies, eggs, or elections?: ")
if ask == 'bunnies':
    bunnies = 30
    print("Bunnies will cost " + str(bunnies) + " dollars each.")
    quantity = int(input("How many would you like to buy?: "))
    cost1 = bunnies * quantity
    tax = (0.089 * cost1)
    final_cost = (cost1 + tax)
    if final_cost == final_cost > 57.89:
        discount1 = (0.13 * final_cost)
        with_discount1 = (final_cost - discount1)
        print("Your total will be " + str(with_discount1) + " with a discount.")
    if final_cost == final_cost < 57.89:
        print("Your total will be " + str(final_cost) + " without a discount")

if ask == 'eggs':
    eggs = 10
    print("Eggs will cost " + str(eggs) + " dollars each.")
    quantity = int(input("How many would you like to buy?: "))
    cost2 = eggs * quantity
    tax = (0.089 * cost2)
    final_cost2 = (cost2 + tax)
    if final_cost2 == final_cost2 > 57.89:
        discount = (0.13 * final_cost2)
        with_discount = (final_cost2 - discount)
        print("Your total will be " + str(with_discount) + " with a discount for eggs.")
    if final_cost2 == final_cost2 < 57.89:
        print("Your total will be " + str(final_cost2) + " without a discount for eggs")

if ask == 'elections':
    elections = 20
    print("Elections will cost " + str(elections) + " dollars.")
    quantity = int(input("How many are you looking to purchase?: "))
    cost3 = quantity * elections
    tax = (0.089 * cost3)
    final_cost3 = (cost3 + tax)
    if final_cost3 == final_cost3 > 57.89:
        discount2 = (0.13 * final_cost3)
        withdiscount = (final_cost3 - discounts)
        print("Your total will be " + str(withdiscount) + " dollars with a discount for elections.")
    if final_cost3 == final_cost3 < 57.89:
        print("Your total will be " + str(final_cost3) + " dollars without a discount for elections.")
```

Answer (score 3):

- Using `from math import *` is highly discouraged. Please always use either:

  - `from math import sqrt`, or
  - `import math` and use `math.sqrt` instead of `sqrt`.
- You are not using `math` and so the import is not needed.
- It is commonly recommended to use either f-strings or `str.format` to format your strings. This is as they make reading the format easier on more complex formats.

  In your case you won't see this benefit too much but it would be a good habit to get now, rather than later.

  ```py
  print("Bunnies will cost {} dollars each.".format(bunnies))
  print(f"Bunnies will cost {bunnies} dollars each.")
  ```
- Please don't use unnecessary parentheses. This is as they add unneeded clutter to your code.
- You can simplify the calculation for `final_cost`

  $$
  \begin{array}{r l}
  c &= bq\\
  t &= 0.089c\\
  f &= c + t\\
  f &= 0.089c + c\\
  f &= (0.089 + 1)c\\
  f &= 1.089bq
  \end{array}
  $$
- The statement `final_cost == final_cost > 57.89` is confusing and only works due to Python splitting the code into two different conditionals connected with an `and`.

  The statement `final_cost == final_cost` will always be true, and so by all metrics is just bad.
- Your ifs are missing if the final cost is 57.89 exactly. I assume this is a mistake.

  When you have two ifs like this when one is getting half the options and the other is getting the other half it is better to use an `if` and an `else` rather than two `if`s.
- You don't need to store `discount1` in a variable, it's just adding lines with no visible benefit.
- Whilst there's nothing inherently wrong with printing the same string with a slight modification twice, you may be inclined to change it so you only define the structure of the print once.

Overall this would get:

```py
bunnies = 30
print(f"Bunnies will cost {bunnies} dollars each.")
quantity = int(input("How many would you like to buy?: "))
final_cost = 1.089 * bunnies * quantity
if final_cost >= 57.89:
    with_discount = final_cost - 0.13 * final_cost
    print(f"Your total will be {with_discount} with a discount")
else:
    print(f"Your total will be {final_cost} without a discount")
```

From here we can see all the other options have almost exactly the same code. There are only three things that change:

1. The variable name `bunnies`.
2. The value of the variable `bunnies`
3. The name of the item you're buying.

From this we can see that a function would be good.

```py
def price_to_buy(item, price):
    print(f"{item} will cost {price} dollars each.")
    quantity = int(input("How many would you like to buy?: "))
    final_cost = 1.089 * price * quantity
    if final_cost >= 57.89:
        with_discount = final_cost - 0.13 * final_cost
        print(f"Your total will be {with_discount} with a discount")
    else:
        print(f"Your total will be {final_cost} without a discount")


ask = input("Would you like to buy bunnies, eggs, or elections?: ")
if ask == "bunnies":
    price_to_buy("Bunnies", 30)
if ask == "eggs":
    price_to_buy("Eggs", 10)
if ask == "elections":
    price_to_buy("Elections", 20)
```

## Advanced changes

Whilst the above is probably what your instructor expects from you, there are more ways to improve the code and make it shorter.

- You can store the name and value in a dictionary, allowing you to condense those ifs into two lines of code.

  You may want to use a `try` and `except` here to get the code to function the same if you don't enter valid input.
- You can use `str.title()` to make the inputted item's name display in title case.
- You can use an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to prevent the code from running when imported, normally by accident.
- You can use a turnery to apply the discount, this is basically just an `if` and `else` but on one line!

  By also using tuple unpacking we can get the preposition (with/without) and the discount percentage in one line.
- You can use a `try` and `except` to display a nice error message.
- You can use `foo -= ...` rather than `foo = foo - ...`.

```py
def price_to_buy(item, price):
    print(f"{item} will cost {price} dollars each.")
    value = input("How many would you like to buy?: ")
    try:
        quantity = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{value} is not an integer.")
        return
    cost = 1.089 * price * quantity
    discount, prep = (0.13, "with") if cost >= 57.89 else (0, "without")
    cost -= discount * cost
    print(f"Your total will be {cost} {prep} a discount")


PRICES = {"bunnies": 30, "eggs": 10, "elections": 20}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    item = input("Would you like to buy bunnies, eggs, or elections?: ")
    price_to_buy(item.title(), PRICES[item])
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers and for explaining it clearly. Studying this right now.